# Why use iter() to make a list an iterable?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterator

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
         self._value = value
         self._children = []
    def __repr__(self):
         return 'Node({!r})'.format(self._value)
    def add_child(self, node):
         self._children.append(node)
    def __iter__(self):
         return iter(self._children)
    def depth_first(self):
         yield self
         for c in self:
             yield from c.depth_first()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(0)
    child1 = Node(1)
    child2 = Node(2)
    root.add_child(child1)
    root.add_child(child2)
    child1.add_child(Node(3))
    child1.add_child(Node(4))
    child2.add_child(Node(5))

for a in root.depth_first():
    print(a)
# Outputs Node(0), Node(1), Node(3), Node(4), Node(2), Node(5)
```

I thought that a list is an object that we can iterate over it so why use `iter()` ? I am new in python so this look to me so weird.

Comment: `iter` doesn't make a list iterable, it returns an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because returning `self._children` returns a `list` object, which doesn't work as an iterator, remember, *iterators* implement the `__next__` method in order to supply items during iteration:

```
>>> next(list())  # doesn't implement a __next__ method
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

`list`s are *iterable*, they can be iterated through because calling `iter` on the will return an *iterator*, but, `list`s themselves are not iterators -- a good breakdown of these can be found in the top answer of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python/237028#237028).

A lists `__iter__` method returns a custom  new `list_iterator` object each time `__iter__` is called:

```
list().__iter__()
Out[93]: <list_iterator at 0x7efe7802d748>
```

and, by doing that, supports iteration multiple times, the `list_iterator` object implements the `__next__` method that's required. 
Calling and returning `iter` on it will just do that, return the lists iterator and save you the trouble of having to implement `__next__`.

---

Addressing your comment as for why `for c in self._children` works, well, because it is essentially doing the same thing. What basically happens with the for loop is:

```
it = iter(self._children)  # returns the list iterator
while True:
    try:
        i = next(it)
        <loop body>
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

meaning, `iter` is called again on the list object and is used by the `for` loop for `next` calls.

Comment: i did't understand what do you mean by returning a list object ? and when i tried this code it worked well `class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
         self._value = value
         self._children = []
    def __repr__(self):
         return 'Node({!r})'.format(self._value)
    def add_child(self, node):
         self._children.append(node)
    def __iter__(self):
         return iter(self._children)
    def depth_first(self):
         yield self
         for c in self._children:
             yield from c.depth_first()`

Comment: why when i change( for c in self:) with (for c in self._children) it work very well

Answer (score 0):

Every iterable object implements an **iter**() function that returns itself.
the iter(obj) calls the obj.**iter**(), which is same as returning the list object in your example.